# Add custom icons to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there a way to use custom icons/shapes with [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=en). I don't want to use the default [pointShapes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points), rather i want to use custom icons say from font awesome, bootstrap icons or google material design.

There used to be a way to do this in the now deprecated google image charts by changing a property named 'd' of the path attribute. Can we do something similar for google charts?

If i inspect the code of the generated **scattered chart** as in jsFiddle code, i can notice that each point has path tags with d properties which i believe can be replaced with the raw values of svg icons. But these elements don't have any id associated with them so no way of editing picking them via javascript and editing them.
Scattered chart's snippet here:

```js
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ 8,      12],
          [ 4,      5.5],
          [ 11,     14],
          [ 4,      5],
          [ 3,      3.5],
          [ 6.5,    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
          hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          legend: 'none',
            pointSize: 20,
            pointShape: 'star'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: It's not that easy, when you take a look at the console, you'll notice that each icon, although it looks the same, has a different path. When you simply update the path with a static value all icons will appear at the same position.

Comment: yes, you're right. I update the 'd' property for each point, but all of them are being displayed on top left. Isn't there any property in google charts itself to specify url or the class name for icons. Or may be some event where we can do the same?

Comment: you can use the `getChartLayoutInterface` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) to find the (x, y) location of the point and add the image manually -- see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771)